# Mention a Teams tag in an adaptive card

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Using the bot framework I am trying to mention a Teams tag in an adaptive card text block. Mentioning a user by e-mail works as expected. When I try to mention a tag by its ID it does not work, it does not result in a mention.

Unless the format of the entity for tag has to be different, I cannot see what I am doing incorrect here.

See the below how I construct the adaptive card (using the AdaptiveCards NuGet package).

```cs
new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 2))
{
    Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>
    {
        new AdaptiveTextBlock
        {
            Text = "Mention test: <at>mytag</at>"
        }
    },
    AdditionalProperties = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {
            "msteams",
            new
            {
                width = "full", 
                entities = new []
                {
                    new Mention()
                    {
                        // Does work when a e-mail is mentioned, but not when I use a Teams tag ID
                        Mentioned = new ChannelAccount("my@mail.com", "mytag"),
                        Text = "<at>mytag</at>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Currently only user mention is supported. Mentioning a tag via payload is not supported yet. You can submit this as feedback at [Microsoft Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT that is unfortunate. Is there another way of sending proactive messages to a Teams channel? I need to be able to mention tags. I don't need to do anything other than sending proactive messages.

Comment: Please check the following document regarding proactive messaging - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet,  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging/csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this is not possible. I submitted feedback requesting this feature.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/daeb1976-f010-ee11-a81c-000d3a7a48db

A workaround I found is using the Microsoft Graph API to request a list of members in a tag. Then mention all the individual members (by e-mail) in the adaptive card using an invisible TextBlock.

Answer (score 1):

The mention tag can be used in the Bot Framework for the Adaptive Card by using the format.

[Click to show the screenshot of Tag group mentioned in Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtVmf.png)
This is the sample of the tag in the Adaptive Card. WHen hove over the message, the group card shows the details. And the mentioned user in the channel can find the message mentioned with a red @ mark.

The main change is to add the "msteams" in the attachments to define the tag group. the   will be used to locate the tag in the message card body.

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.3",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "**And this mentions tag** <at>your tag name</at>!",
                        "size": "Medium",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ],
                "msteams": {
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "type": "mention",
                            "text": "<at>your tag name</at>",
                            "mentioned": {
                                "id": "your tag GUID",
                                "name": "display string for the tag",
                                "type": "tag"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```